# Thinking OOP in JavaScript / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, procedural-programming

I understand well the concepts of OOP and prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, but sometimes, I wonder how to make use of these in real world applications.

I'll take as an exemple a simple(istic) [contact management web application](https://github.com/Buzut/Contacts-pro) I pushed on GitHub a couple of months ago.

In the main handler mainly reside functions:

```
var UserModel = require('../models/userModel.js');
var checkObjectId = new RegExp('^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$');
var root;

exports.getContacts = function(request, response) {
    var id = JSON.parse(request.params.user)[0];

    // validate
    if (!checkObjectId.test(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Not a user id'});
    }

    UserModel.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        response.send(user.contacts);
    });
};

exports.addContact = function(request, response) {
    var id = JSON.parse(request.params.user)[0];

    // validate
    if (!checkObjectId.test(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Not a user id'});
    }

    UserModel.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        var contact = {};

        // avoid to save empty info
        if (request.body.first.length > 1) {contact.first = request.body.first;}
        if (request.body.last.length > 1) {contact.last = request.body.last;}
        if (request.body.mobile.length > 1) {contact.mobile = request.body.mobile;}
        if (request.body.home.length > 1) {contact.home = request.body.home;}
        if (request.body.office.length > 1) {contact.office = request.body.office;}
        if (request.body.email.length > 1) {contact.email = request.body.email;}
        if (request.body.company.length > 1) {contact.company = request.body.company;}
        if (request.body.description.length > 1) {contact.description = request.body.description;}
        if (request.body.keywords.length > 1) {contact.keywords = request.body.keywords;}

        user.contacts.push(contact);

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }

            console.log('contact saved');
            response.send(user.contacts);
        });
    });
};

exports.updateContact = function(request, response) {
    var id = JSON.parse(request.params.user)[0];

    // validate
    if (!checkObjectId.test(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Not a user id'});
    }

    var contact = {
        _id: request.body._id,
        first: request.body.first,
        last: request.body.last,
        mobile: request.body.mobile,
        home: request.body.home,
        office: request.body.office,
        email: request.body.email,
        company: request.body.company,
        description: request.body.description,
        keywords: request.body.keywords
    };

    UserModel.update({_id: id, "contacts._id": request.body._id}, {$set: {"contacts.$": contact}}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        response.sendStatus(user);
    });
};

exports.deleteContact = function(request, response) {
    var id = JSON.parse(request.params.user)[0];

    // validate
    if (!checkObjectId.test(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Not a user id'});
    }

    return UserModel.update({_id: id}, {$pull: {contacts: {_id: request.params.id}}}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        console.log('contact removed');
        console.log(user);
        response.sendStatus(user);
    });
};
```

It doesn't do much: fetch data from DB and return them or take data from user and save them to DB.

If it was a bit more complexe, I would surely place some logic in separate functions to reuse them and break down complexity.

Nevertheless, this code looks rather procedural, so does the hypothetical more complex version with separate functions. How would it be organized in a OOP way and how would I gain from it?

For instance, would I benefit from a User constructor?

Comment: I think your code is ideal to split into an object. The reason is the name of your functions which intonate an object candidate, i.e. addContact, getContacts, updateContact...they all use the noun `contact`. So create a  separate module called contact with a function constructor and at the top of your code use `var contact = new Contact();` It's then easier to extrapolate functionality into this new module and interface with contact.update(), etc

Comment: Sure I can do that, but since I have a handler for specific things (like contact handler, mail handler…), I'm not sure I'd gain from doing `var contact = new Contact();` and then `exports.getContacts = contact.getContact();` or would I?

Comment: in your main handler file, you could create an array and then push onto it a new contact, `var contacts = [];` and then when you invoke `addContact()`, you would do `contacts.push(new Contact('stuff'));`. The whole point is that the object would handle all the stuff you have in your main file, which is the primary objective of encapsulation.

Comment: I see, I'll give that a try!

Comment: @user1717735: You should make a `Contact.fromRequest` method, and then put the rest as methods there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing you could do is nest the instance of your constructor inside an initializing function so you wouldn't have to repeat your validation code.

```
var connection = (function() {

  var UserModel = require('../models/userModel.js');
  var notAUser = {error: 'Not a user id'};

  function init(request, response) {   
    var status = validate(JSON.parse(request.params.user)[0]);
    if (!status.id) return response.status(400).json(status);
    return new Connect(request, response, status.id);
  }

  function Connect(request, response, id) {
    this.request = request;
    this.response = response;
    this.id = id;
    this.info = { _id: id, "contacts._id": request.body._id };
  }

  function validate(id) {
    if (!/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/.test(id)) return notAUser;
    else return {id: id};
  }

  Connect.prototype.getContact = function() {} 
  //etc...

  return init;

})();

module.exports = connection;
```

Then in your actual application

```
var connection = require("./connection.js");
someAsync(data, function(req, res) {
    var query = connection(req, res); //returned instance of constructor
    query.getContact(someData, callback);    
});
```

Comment: I loooove this pattern. Thus, I was kind of puzzled at first as the constructor is an IEF expression. I find it clearer to declare a proper function like `function connection() {…}` and then do `module.exports = connection();`

Comment: By the way, why naming it "connection"? It's rather a contact factory to me…

Comment: @user1717735 a common API pattern is to create a connection object that has RESTFUL methods attached to it. This way, your application logic isn't tightly coupled to "create contact" but to "create [something]" and it could be a contact, user, product, anything. Check out the mysql api for nodejs to see an example https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/

Comment: Thank you for the exemple. Would I have a connection object that would have both contact and user REST methods? Or is it two different objects that are called connecion because they handle objets' REST methods? Anyway I don't manage users and contacts in the same handler…

Answer (score 1):

I would start by encapsulating the `request` and `response` since every method needs those. Like:

```
var contact = function (request, response) {
    return {
        add: add
    }

    function add() {
        // add() gets access request and response for free
    }
};
```

OR, if you are keen on the new operator:

```
function Contact(request, response) {
    this.request = request;
    this.response = response;
}

Contact.prototype.add = function () {
    this.request;
}
```

Then move repeated code and callbacks to private methods you can reuse inside the object.

Comment: Thank you both beautifulcoder & Daniel_L. I'm sorry I took a long time to answer. I wanted to think about this all to apprehend it better. I'll try to avoid `new` as much as possible since it is error prone and I'll go with the factory function.

Comment: Major difference between the two ways here though is that the first function adds `add()` in the instance itself whereas the second one adds it to its prototype.